# Microsoft Access 2016 - "Clear Filters from [Field]" Dropdown menu grayed out

Tags: microsoft-access

I am using Microsoft Access 2016. I have a tiny table that has 4 fields and 300 records. I am able to use the right click menu at the top to add filters to individual fields.. but after I add a filter, I am unable to use that right-click/down-arrow menu to choose to CLEAR the field's filter. I can use the "Clear All Filters" buttons.. but the individual field filter cannot be cleared as it is grayed out to signify that it is unusable.

PS: This table viewed in datasheet mode. I am not using any sort of forms whatsoever.

[EDIT TO ADD:  It appears that once I choose to filter a single field with the dropdown menu item that immediately Access forgets it ever had a larger dataset.  I am able to add ANOTHER individual filter on the field as if that field were showing me all of its data already.]

Comment: I can't get it to do the same thing in my Access 2016, either with .accdb or .mdb files.  Have you tried restarting Access or the computer? What about a compact/repair on the database?  Does it do it in other databases?  The closest thing I can see is if I put the filter on one column and try and clear it from a different column, the clear option is greyed out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have compacted/repaired the database.  I have verified that this dumb thing happens on different installations of Access.  I have not tried .mdb... but I will try that next.  I think I will also try exporting the table to a brand new database.  ... I believe after that I will try cursing at my machine and throwing it out the window. :) Thx!!

Comment: It appears that once I choose to filter a single field with the dropdown menu item that immediately Access forgets it ever had a larger dataset. I am able to add ANOTHER individual filter on the field as if that field were showing me all of its data already - I will add this to the original question.